# Browser on Apple devices such as iPads which support flash games and flash websites?

Tags: gratis, ipad-app, flash

I am looking for a browser that is free on the App Store that can view content that requires flash player, supports websites that use flash player and allows me to be able to play flash games from devices such as iPads.

I have heard that there are some browsers that support this but I am quite skeptical as to whether or not it works or not, whether the reviews are genuine and because they all cost and I am looking for a free app.

Is there a free browser on the Apple App Store which supports this?

Comment: Did you check that app? Was it helpful? Please provide feedback on the answer, and also let us know if you found another browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Puffin Web Browser](http://www.puffinbrowser.com/index.php) is the one that I use regularly. Not only it supports Flash, but also it has an embedded proxy, so that you can browse the internet anonymously, or even bypass censorship if your service provider thinks that they should decide what websites you should visit!

You can get the free version from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser-free/id472937654?mt=8), but there's also a paid version of it available [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser/id406239138?mt=8). I've never purchased the paid version, since I'm quite happy with the free one. However I sometimes find it a little bit laggy when trying to fast-forward or rewind videos, but still it's better than nothing! (:

Comment: I use Puffin at my job and there is a version of it for Android now as well. The pay version supposedly gets rid of ads but honestly I am very happy with the free version. Puffin uses the Chrome browser engine with Flash installed.